# how to make large image clickable on different different image part

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, zooming

I want to implement a application in this application multiple click event like periodic table i want to use large image for this and make image clickable from its different different part called element in this implementation zoom and scroll feature are also include

Comment: the simplest way you can create the relative layout with small chunk of images

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Define a Rect for the spot/area that you would like to make clickable. Also remember to redifine it based on screen layout size and resolution.

Now onTouch event get the x and y position and calculate whether it lies within the defined Rect and act accordingly. The Rects will act as virtual image maps.

Comment: yap i think its possible solution if any code available for this then please tell me

Comment: @AlokTiwari Just FYI: Stack Overflow does not tend to just provide you code when you haven't done any work to begin with. Don't expect people to write your code for you here. If you *have* code already, we'll help you with *specific* problems with it - but we're not going to just throw 'sample code' at you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to divide your large image into sub images and add these sub images to every image view. You have to create a layout such that all these image views must show the original large image without any disturbance at corners, then only you can get separate click events for each sub image.

Comment: but in this implementation image management vary complex can we use motion event class for this

Comment: i think if you are using motion event, the image must fit in the screen. check it once.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a good idea.

Use a "layer" with different alpha level areas. Each area with a specific alpha level is a specific action-click.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/_6u3Iu-sYrI/DA0KCo8pTksJ